# WPF Ribbon and Plugin

Tags: wpf, plugins, ribbon

I'm looking into using the Office Ribbon UI to help navigate around my application and provide different tools for the current selected tab.

I need the Ribbon to be plugable. Each plugin has its own tab and using a DataTemplate displays what's needed.

The main control area will have a navigation on the left and a Tab Control on the right. Multple tabs will be open most of the time.

Ok questions:
1. Is the Ribbon control the correct control for the job
2. How do i dynamically add Tabs to the Ribbon control through my View Model
3. Does anyone know how to define DataTemplates in an external assembly. I need to avoid configurations inside my main application IE make it plugable :D

FYI. The application is a POS system

Comment: Are you using the WPF Ribbon created by MS on CodePlex?

Comment: I'm using the MS Ribbon control from CodePlex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Office Ribbon was the wrong choice for my design.

I've seen posts on using Prism with Office Ribbon to get plugins working